# Calculating amount of patients in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with patients that have answered twice in same questionnaire in couple of years.

Now I need to calculate how many patient developed problem, how many improved and how many maintained having problems. The answers are in scale 1-6 where `<3` is no problem, `3-4.75` is sometimes problem and `>= 5` is problems.

I have merged these two dataframe to one and tried to calculate difference by coding

```
dat5$noproblem = ((dat5$sleepProblems.x)<3)-((dat5$sleepProblems.y)<3)
```

but I only get a dataframe there is zero and minus 1 and which dimension is NULL. 
I tried do the same with

```
diff((dat5$sleepProblems.x<3) - lag((dat5$sleepProblems.y<3)))
```

but I still get just list of different values.

How I can get the amount of patients?

(Sorry for unclear description)

EDIT: 
Note that organisation is changed from real number to x in order to maintain the privacy of the individuals

```
structure(list(Organisation = c("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", 
"XXX", "XXX"), VAR066_1 = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), VAR066_3 = c(3L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 2L), VAR066_5 = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L), VAR066_6 = c(2L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 2L), sleepProblems.x = c(2.75, 2.5, 4.5, 2.5, 2), 
    VAR074_1 = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), VAR074_3 = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L), VAR074_5 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), VAR074_6 = c(3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), sleepProblems.y = c(2.5, 2, 3.25, 2.75, 
    3.25), sleepingproblems = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), noproblem = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add some data (also fake data) to have the idea of your dataset (and an example of the desired output)?

Comment: Thanks! How I do that? My data is basically peoples organization number, sleeping problem x answerd as number between 1-6 and sleeping problem y answered as number between 1-6.

Comment: see my answer, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Here a base R solution:

```
# first you calculate the kpi that defines if it's problem or not
dat5$kpi <- dat5$sleepProblems.x - dat5$sleepProblems.y
# second you can use ifelse to see if there is problem or not
dat5$noproblem <- ifelse(dat5$kpi < 3,"no problem", 
                         ifelse(dat5$kpi >= 5, "problem","sometimes problem"))

  Organisation VAR066_1 VAR066_3 VAR066_5 VAR066_6 sleepProblems.x VAR074_1 VAR074_3 VAR074_5 VAR074_6 sleepProblems.y sleepingproblems
1          XXX        3        3        3        2            2.75        3        2        2        3            2.50                0
2          XXX        2        2        4        2            2.50        2        2        2        2            2.00                0
3          XXX        3        5        5        5            4.50        3        4        3        3            3.25                0
4          XXX        3        2        3        2            2.50        3        3        3        2            2.75                0
5          XXX        2        2        2        2            2.00        3        4        3        3            3.25                1
   noproblem   kpi
1 no problem  0.25
2 no problem  0.50
3 no problem  1.25
4 no problem -0.25
5 no problem -1.25
```

Note: my `ifelse` considers the ranges `kpi<3`, `kpi>= 5` and  `3=<kpi<5`, that's different from your, because it works also for `4.75<x<5`, that it's not specified in your question what to do with that range.

To get the numbers in the groups, there are many ways, one is (in this case, one group, due the data) to do this after the previous code:

```
table(dat5$noproblem)
no problem 
         5
```

Comment: I tried to do that but I got Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, kpi, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 872 as answer. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @Tinde could you post (editing your question) the output of `dput(head(dat5,5))` ? In that way you're going to share the first 5 rows of the data and making the troubleshooting easier.

Comment: I am afraid that it did not work. I got a list saying no problem, problem or sometimes problem but I would need the number of these groups (ie how many developed problem, how many improved and how many maintained in no problem or problem group)

Comment: If the answer is correct, you can [mark it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as correct, it's going to give to you and me some reputation and help to find the answer in the community. It's not compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (and defining the kpi as @s_t suggests), with `dplyr::case_when` you can code it up as follows:

```r
dat5$kpi <- dat5$sleepProblems.x - dat5$sleepProblem.y
dat5 <- dat5 %>%
  mutate(noproblem = case_when(
         kpi < 3 ~ "no problem",
         kpi >= 5 ~ "problem",
         TRUE ~ "sometimes problem"
   )
)
```

or to "wrap" everything into the `mutate` statement as:

```r
dat5 <- dat5 %>%
  mutate(kpi = sleepProblems.x - sleepProblems.y,
         noproblem = case_when(
         kpi < 3 ~ "no problem",
         kpi >= 5 ~ "problem",
         TRUE ~ "sometimes problem"
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do dat5$kpi but I get an error message instead saying Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, kpi, value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 872 as answer. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Without the whole data set or a sample of it, it's very difficult to troubleshoot. If that cannot be done, can you copy-paste the output of `str(dat5)`?